# Loading a simple html page which closes the current "tab" with trigger.io?

Tags: trigger.io

I have a mobile html5 app which uses Trigger.io. At some point, I need to open an external web page, and I'm using `forge.tab.open` to achieve it. It works fine. However, after the user interacts with the window, I need the tab to close and I'm not getting there.

On my regular web page I'm forwarding to a simple HTML page that contains `<body onload="self.close();">` and that works fine.

On the trigger.io app, I tried using `<body onload="forge.tabs.closeCurrent();">` and that does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way for you to achieve this is to specify a match pattern when opening the tab, redirecting the user to a url matching that pattern will then cause the tab to close.

See the docs for more details http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/features/modal.html#match-pattern

Comment: Forwarding to forge:///close did the trick for me. Thanks for the quick response.